# Why is the text so blurry or jaggy in 320x240 resolution?

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, interface, 2d-games

So I was trying to make a dialogue box for test but encounter a problem;

So I have my text very clear on Scene but when I play the game the text becomes very blur or jaggy.[image]

so here I put it side by side to see the huge difference in appearance

Is there a way to not make it look like that?

Comment: I have noticed that your Game View scale is 1.47 which may lead to the text being too "pixelized". The text quality depends on many factors, mainly: the font settings (like smoothing or pixel density) and of course on how big is the text in terms of pixel=s on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I see two things that might cause this. On the top of the scene, you set the resolution to 320x240. This also applies to the UI so have might be what makes the text pixilated.

The other is that your UI has a constant pixel size. Instead, you should select `Scale With Sceen Size` so the UI scales with the screen. This is less likely to cause the problem but it might still help.

[image]